How to avoid the automatic redirection to the login page after the registration page but redirect to the authentication for submitting the pin?
# I am using Java 21,
# Spring boot 3.3.4,
# Spring security.
# 
***The process is :
form register --> save userEntity credentials and also save a tokenEntity for authentication.
I send mail with the token.
Page with form to enter the token received by mail
and then login.***

**After submitting the form the business logic is ok.  User and token are saved in the    database.**

**The problem is that after submitting the register form, spring redirects to the authenticate page and immediately the login page.

See image:**

**SecurityFilterChain:**

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers(
                            antMatcher(LOGIN_MAPPING),
                            antMatcher("/logout"),
                            antMatcher("/register"),
                            antMatcher("/static/css/*"),
                            antMatcher("/images/*"),
                            antMatcher("/answer"),
                            antMatcher("/game"),
                            antMatcher("/result"),
                            antMatcher("/activate-account")
                            ).permitAll();
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                    });
        http.formLogin(form->form.loginPage(LOGIN_MAPPING)
                        .permitAll()
                        .loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_MAPPING)
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/game" ,true))
                .logout(LogoutConfigurer::permitAll);
        return http.build();
    }


**AuthController:**

    @Slf4j
    @Controller
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class AuthController {
        private final AuthService authService;
        private final MyUserService userService;
    
        @GetMapping("/login")
        String getLoginPage() {
            return "login";
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/register")
        public String getRegisterPage(Model model){
            model.addAttribute("user" , MyUser.builder().build());
            return "register";
        }
    
        @PostMapping("/register")
        String registration(@ModelAttribute MyUser user) {
            userService.registerUser(user);
            return "redirect:/activate_account";
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/activate-account")
        public String confirm(Model model) {
            return "/activate_account";
        }
    
        @PostMapping("/activate-account")
        public String confirm(@RequestParam(value = "token") String token, Model model){
            authService.activateAccount(token);
            return "redirect:login?success";
        }
    }

**register.html:**

    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="it" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <head th:replace="/partial/head"></head>
    <body>
    <div th:replace="/partial/nav"></div>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 90px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <form th:action="@{/register}" method="post" class="card col-md-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title mb-4">Please register</h5>
                    <!-- Email input -->
                    <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                        <input name="username" type="email" id="username" class="form-control"/>
                        <label class="form-label" for="username">Email address</label>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Password input -->
                    <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                        <input name="password" type="password" id="password" class="form-control"/>
                        <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Submit button -->
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control mb-4">Sign on</button>
                    <!-- Register buttons -->
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div th:replace="/partial/script"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
    </body>
    </html>

Has anyone experienced this problem yet?
If so, how did you solve it?
# **Thank you in advance for any suggestions.**

I tried eliminating ‘    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();’ in the filter.
Expecting no redirection to the login page but always returns to the login.
I thought of introducing a check at the beginning of the login controller to identify whether the user had passed from the register page and in case he was and his token was not yet authenticated redirect him to the register.
But that's not the solution I'd like to adopt because it's not clean and I don't like checking every user who wants to land on the login page.

I solved:
@PostMapping("/register")
String registration(@ModelAttribute MyUser user) {
    userService.registerUser(user);
    return "/activate_account";
}


SOLVED:
    @PostMapping("/register")
    String registration(@ModelAttribute MyUser user) {
        userService.registerUser(user);
        return "/activate_account";
    }


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Thank you Jeremy, it is a pleasure, I'll do it soon.
I am finding an even better solution that I will explain in detail.
